# writing return value from a method of type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get info from a connected service that I added to my simple c# console app.

Here is what I am running in Visual Studio:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAuth iAuth = new AuthClient();
        Console.WriteLine("\nYour server version:\n ");

        string result = iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue ...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);

    }
}
```

When I run it, I don't get any errors, but I just get this returned:

```
Your server version:

System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

Press any key to continue ...
```

GetServerVersionAsync() is part of an API and looks like this:

```
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetServerVersionAsync()
    {
        return base.Channel.GetServerVersionAsync();
    }
```

How do I get it to return an usable value?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to implement `async/await` all the way down the tree. Your `GetServerVersionAsync()` method needs to be async, and it should _await_ the result of `base.Channel.GetServerVersionAsync();`.  Never versions of C# allow for the `main()` method to be async as well

Comment: @maccettura Making that change would change literally nothing about how the program behaves.  Creating an asynchronous method that calls another asynchronous method, returns its result, and does nothing else, is no different from just calling that method.

Comment: @Servy awaiting a task does not return the _actual_ value (i.e a `string`)?  Unless I am missing something with my pre-lunch brain?  I did not specifically include the `await` in main in my comment, but the first thing I did say was it needs to be async all the way down

Comment: @maccettura Yes, the value the expression `await aTaskReturningExpression` does resolve to the result of the task represented by `aTaskReturningExpression`.  But again, adding `await` there *change literally nothing about the program*.  It's important for an asynchronous program to be *asynchronous* all the way down, but you don't need to use the `async` keyword to do that.  If you can write an asynchronous method without that keyword, that's fine.  They keyword is just a way of writing complex asynchronous methods more easily.

Comment: @maccettura so my main method needs to have async in front of it?  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell No, it doesn't.  That won't change anything about how the program behaves.

Comment: @Servy re-reading my comment and it does come off a bit misleading.  I should have actually got to the crux of the problem instead of focusing more on an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you never get the *result* of your task.  To do that you need to `await` the task, or to access the task's result.  The latter will block your main thread until the task is complete.

If you are using C# 7.1 or higher, you can use `async Main()` so you can await the task:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //some code
    string result = await iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync();
    //Some more code
}
```

If you are using a version of C# lower than 7.1 you can just block the thread until your async method completes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //some code
    string result = iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync().Result;
    //Some more code
}
```

**EDIT** judging by the equal upvotes and downvotes it seems like my blurb about making `GetServerVersionAsync()` async was not received as I intended.  Obviously making that method async does not fix the problem, but since the method is suffixed with the word "Async" and it calls an `async` method, it seemed wise to make it `async` for clarity.

Comment: I am running c# 7.0 so I used the 2nd example you provided and it worked great!  Thanks!

Comment: I wrote my answer, with screenshots and all, and only then I noticed your answer which is 11 hours old. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

While other answers show you how to make-it-work, the correct solution is to make Main `async`, which is available from C♯7.1 since 2017 (see [What's new in C# 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1)) .

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args) // <-- not 'void', but 'async Task' 
    {
        //Option 1. The best: async Task Main

        IAuth iAuth = new AuthClient();
        Console.WriteLine("\nYour server version:\n");

        var version = await iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync(); //<---- key word 'await'

        Console.WriteLine(version);
        Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue ...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

If you get *Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point* error you may need to set the C♯ version in project properties.

[image]

The interaction between non-`async` and `async` worlds is tricky, sometimes very and it should be avoided. Please see [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

---

**Option 2 - non-async Main**

Even if you decide you don't want `async Taks Main` I suggest having a helper method that is `async`. I think it's a better habit to develop. From inside this helper method you can use `XAsync()` methods with the await keyword, the way it's intended.

Here's an example.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Option 1. Not the best: void Main

        //Mixing async and non-async worlds - avoid if possible.
        //See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c
        Task t = MyMethodAsync();
        t.Wait();
    }

    private static async Task MyMethodAsync() {  

        IAuth iAuth = new AuthClient();
        Console.WriteLine("\nYour server version:\n");

        string version = await iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync(); //<---- key word 'await'

        Console.WriteLine(version);
        Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue ...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync().Result;
```

And then u can cast it to string with.

```
var stringResult = result.ToString();
```

Comment: FYI: Result is a property, not a method.

Comment: And what is supposed to do the line _var stringResult = result.ToString();_ ?

Comment: @maccettura absolutely, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
string result = iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync().ToString();
```

to

```
string result = iAuth.GetServerVersionAsync().Result;
```